# use Matlab's PDE toolbox to solve PDE with variable coefficients

Tags: pde, matlab

I'm new to the PDE toolbox in `Matlab`. From the PDE specification window of the toolbox, it looks like one can only solve PDE with constant coefficients.

[image]

How can I use `Matlab`'s PDE toolbox to solve PDE like

$$
\partial_t P(x,y,t)=x\partial_xP(x,y,t)+(y-1)\partial_yP(x,y,t)+2P(x,y,t)?
$$

Comment: This question would best be asked on the [Mathworks forums](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, PDE Toolbox is able to solve 2D PDE in the form shown on this page:

[PDE Form](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/types-of-pde-problems-you-can-solve.html)

Any of those coefficients (e.g. c, a, f, d) can be functions of x, y, t, u,
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$.

If the coefficients are relatively simple expressions, the simplest way to define them is by typing a string expression in text boxes above (e.g. 1+x.^2+4*y). That approach is documented on this page:

[Coefficients defined with string expressions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/scalar-coefficients-in-string-form.html)

If the coefficients are more complicated, it is usually more straightforward to define
them as MATLAB functions. That approach is documented on this page:

[Coefficients defined with a function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/scalar-coefficients-in-function-form.html)

For your equation, f could be defined as the string `"x.^ux+(y-1).*uy"` (without the "),
a=-2, d=1, and c=0.

However, a strong caveat is in order. The algorithms in PDE Toolbox are designed for the case where the second-order c-term is significant relative to the first-order derivative terms. So the success for this equation will depend very much on the boundary and initial conditions. It might also be necessary to set c to some small number; this is sometimes referred to as adding "artificial diffusion."

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, from the PDE Form documentation, it looks like all equations types that can be solved by PDE toolbox involve only 2nd-order spatial derivatives but no 1st-order spatial derivatives.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I read your second sentence and didn't look as closely at your PDE as I should have. In PDE Toolbox, the coefficients, themselves, can be functions of first-order spatial derivatives of the dependent variables so you could include them in the f-coefficient. But you are correct that it is designed to handle PDE that have a significant diffusion term.

Comment: How do I express, for example, f=$x\partial_xu$ in Matlab?

Comment: I updated my original response to cover this question and say a bit more about using PDE Toolbox for first-order equations.

Comment: Indeed, PDE tool cannot solve the PDE when $c$=0.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this PDE toolbox in Matlab, but the software COMSOL Multiphysics is developed from this toolbox. You can dig a bit to find out their close relation. Also if you check out COMSOL you will find how these two look alike.

At least in COMSOL, I know your PDE is in principle possible to solve.

Comment: I'm happy to know such package but it looks like an overkill.